# My Lua OOP Implementation

Tags: class, oop, inheritance, lua, lua-table

I'm messing around with Lua, trying to get OOP to work, ran into some issues and everything works on my end, but I want to know if I'm missing anything, or an unexpected issue will come up using this method to implement oop.

Basically I have a base class

```
local BaseClass = {}
function BaseClass.new()
    local self = setmetatable({}, BaseClass)
    return self
end
```

And then a child class

```
local ChildClass = {}
function ChildClass.new()
    local self = BaseClass.new()
    return self
end
```

Again, everything works, the childclass inherits all the members from the base class, and to my understanding methods are basically variables in lua, so it also inherits those, and then I can add specific members to childclass, and call those. So if it could be better (but still relatively lightweight), if I'll be hit with an unexpected issue or I'm doing something redundant, please let me know.

Comment: It is unclear what is the question. If you want a code review, post it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Your method is wrong: your instances of ChildClass will NOT see methods located in ChildClass table (but they will see methods from BaseClass table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're breaking the chain. The table returned from `ChildClass.new` will have no association with the `ChildClass` table.

You'll want to take a look at [Chapter 16 of Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html), which discusses a typical approach to implementing Object Oriented Programming.

What it boils down to is that you need to use the implicit `self`, by way of the `:` descriptor, if you want to maintain a chain. You don't need to manually define the `ChildClass` constructor, but rather let it inherit the one from `BaseClass` by making it an *instance* of sorts.

```
local BaseClass = {}

function BaseClass:new()
    self.__index = self
    return setmetatable({}, self)
end

local ChildClass = BaseClass:new()
```

Now you can define shared functions for instances of `ChildClass`.

```
function ChildClass:foo ()
    print('foo!')
end

local child_inst = ChildClass:new()
child_inst:foo()
```